# Parameterising Partial Functions By Error Type

Tags: haskell, error-handling, typeclass

I have a situation in which the majority of the operations I am using are partial functions. I want the return type of the functions to vary depending on the context, which should determine the kind of exception handling that occurs, and the type of errors that are reported. My current solution is to define a function parameterised by an error type, then implement the operation as an open function using type classes. For example, the following is an implementation of *head*, assuming a suitable implementation of *Error* and *MonadError* for *Maybe* in terms of the unit type:

```
class (Error e, MonadError e m) => Head m e | m -> e where
  head :: [a] -> m a

errorHead :: (Error e, MonadError e m) => e -> [a] -> m a
errorHead e []       = throwError e
errorHead e (x : xs) = return x

instance Head Maybe () where
  head = errorHead ()

instance Head (Either String) String where
  head = errorHead "error: empty list"
```

The advantage of this implementation is that different errors can be thrown depending on the context in which *head* is called. The question I have is whether this can be accomplished without defining the function using an auxiliary operation and open functions. If not, the second question is whether this solution is optimal. In particular, is there a better way to achieve this behavior?

Comment: You might want to have a look at the [failure](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/failure/latest/doc/html/Control-Failure.html) package.

Comment: I would just define the functions with return types suited for the situation, such as `Maybe a` and `Either a b`. There are plenty of interfaces for these types, already defined as class instances. It is then very easy to react to failure.

Comment: I think the code you've posted has swapped `m` and `e` in the `class` declaration, yes?

Comment: also take a look at the very cool [control-monad-exception](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/control-monad-exception)

Comment: hammar, jberryman: thanks for the references to the failure and control-monad-exception packages. From a quick survey, both appear to implement some or all of the functionality that I was looking for, without the awkwardness of my implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The http://hackage.haskell.org/package/errors package has many utilities for moving between `Maybe`, `Either`, `MaybeT`, and `EitherT`.